# About elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I need to provide many elasticSearch instances for different clients but hosted in my infrastructre.

For the moment it is only some small instances.

I am wondering if it is not better to build a big ElastSearch Cluster with 3-5 servers to handle all instances and then each client gets a different index in this cluster and each instance is distributed over servers.

Or maybe another idea?

And another question is about quorum, what is the quorum for ES please?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to assign each client to different index, Elasticsearch cluster will automatically share loading among all nodes which share shards.

If you are not sure how many nodes are needed, start from a small cluster then keep monitoring the health status of cluster. Add more nodes to the cluster if server loading is high; remove nodes if server loading is low.

When the cluster continuously grow, you may need to assign a [dedicated role](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html) to each node. In this way, you will have more control over the cluster, easier to diagnose the problem and plan resources. For example, adding more master nodes to stabilize the cluster, adding more data nodes to increase searching and indexing performance, adding more coordinate nodes to handle client requests.

A [quorum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#split-brain) is defined as majority of eligible master nodes in cluster as follows:

```
(master_eligible_nodes / 2) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reponse, that's great!! I just noticed that my developers are using the same index name for all clients, this will affect the cluster right ? I mean the data will be mixed?

Comment: Yes. Records share the same index name will be saved under the same index and apply the index settings of shards, be separated among nodes in cluster.